# Lightweight Solution for Unity Project Backend

Tags: unity-game-engine, backend

I am building a multiplayer game in Unity for iOS and have come to a point in choosing which backend to use... I have been weighing the options of BaaS or just creating my own. I would much rather use something like a BaaS because I just don't want to have to worry much about security etc... But the problem I have with all the current BaaS solutions (GameSparks, PlayFab, Firebase..) is that they all are 50+ MB and add a ton of clutter to my project.

Are there any BaaS Solutions that are lighter weight than these? Or am I just going to have to create my own that is very very basic?